# No Item quantity in /v1/loc/items and missing useful data in /v1/loc/inventory

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to have a google sheet sync inventory.

Importing https://connect.squareup.com/v1/(location)/items, it doesn't include the item's quantity, even though it includes almost everything else

If I import https://connect.squareup.com/v1/(location)/inventory it shows quantities but only for variation Ids, and no item names.

Does anyone know how to get an item library INCLUDING the product name?

PS - 
I would ideally like to import the output of the item library export. The link for that is:
https://squareup.com/api/v3/items-bulk/export

I'm guessing this may be an option in API v3 later...

Comment: OK after saving some changes in square's item library it looks like nw variations are either not gettting a unique ID or being given the same id as the first variation....

Comment: Interesting! You might be the first person using Square's APIs with gsheets. We are currently working on upgrading our item and inventory functionality, but I'm not totally clear in what you want. If you want to import the output of the item library export, why don't you do that?

Comment: Well I'm trying to make my own inventory system using sheets/forms for purchase orders and whatnot. I'd like it to automatically refresh from the JSON feed.

FYI: The current version I'm using has an import tab where you just upload the csv file and it update the whole workbook. I have tabs that query specific things for a cleaner look, tabs to help do cycle counts, and a tab that can filter based on category and other things.  I have a tab that pulls low inventory with editable fields to the right for order amount. It can easily be emailed from sheets attached as a clean colorful pdf.

Comment: Two things that would make square's output more friendly would be

1. A target stock amount. (this isn't just for output, but a good feature in general) This could easily just generate a purchase order automatically based on the current amount and target amount.

2. Quantities on the list item end point.

3. Like oyu can limit the end point, being able to change the order to descending would help too. There are parsing issues with the current script i'm using that a feed in descending order would fix. That's really only because i'm figuring out the coding as I'm going though

Comment: Like I said, we are going to be releasing new inventory management APIs that will hopefully solve some of these issues. Would you be willing to show some of your sheets to me? I'd love to know how you are doing this and make a generalized version available to others who might be interested.

Comment: Would be happy to. This is to help my dad's business that is going to start up soon. but i have my main job as a national training manager which takes up time. So once i can polish it up, I'll put it fake data and share in a week or so hopefully.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tS5kV61iEUs7DUE2E9p2rkb6apADfBP28yBZUg1D6Nw/edit?usp=sharing

That is a link to a copy what I'm currently working with, replacing the data on the import tab with the csv file to sumple sync the inventory. See the Extra info tab, and how it helps with the purchase order automation. 

I'm sure this whole doc and formulas could be done more efficiently by an expert, but it may still be useful to you

Comment: Can you email me and I can share with you my ALMOST successful attempts at turning the import tab totally automated with the JSON feed. If I can figure out how to parse it correctly, I think I can do what I want. I'm using a modified version of the popular appscript script "importJSON", with added code to allow the token bearer. The script in the script editor has my bearer token and such, so I'd rather share directly to a square employee from a square email than post on here if you would still find looking at it beneficial. ikeahloe@gmail.com

Comment: did you get my message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to match up the inventory and parent items yourself. Square is working on updated inventory and item management endpoints for the v2 APIs, so be on the lookout for those!